# If f([-1,2])=[2,8] and f is differentiable, prove there exists c$\in$[-1,2] such that |f'(c)| $\geq$2

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, mean-value-theorem

> If f([-1,2])=[2,8] and f is differentiable, prove there exists c$\in$[-1,2] such that |f'(c)| $\geq$2

All I can see is that |f(2)-f(-1)| $\leq$ 6 and |2-(-1)| $\leq$ 3, so any $c_1$ and $c_2$ in [-1,2] will fulfill these 2 conditions, and that I probably need to use Mean Value Theorem.

Any help is apreciated, thanks!

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Hint 1**: The image of $f$ is $[2,8]$, so there must be numbers $x,y\in[-1,2]$ such that $f(x)=2$ and $f(y)=8$.
- **Hint 2**: Indeed you need to use the mean value theorem. It states that there is an $a$ such that $f'(a)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$. Can you argue why the magnitude of this fraction is $\geq2$?
- **Remark**: Note that both $x<y$ and $x>y$ are possible.

Comment: I was able to show 2 when $x-y\geq0 $ but I´m having problems on the other case

Comment: @Albi write out your solution and it might be clearer

Comment: ok, I see the problem I was doing, forgot to switch the in inequality, $\leq$ to $\geq $, when multiplying by $f(x)-f(y)$, now everything is right. Thank you all!